# file explorer changes

Tags: files, 20.04, ls

I have downloaded a file onto the working directory and can see the file when I look at file explorer. However, the file does not show up when I use the ls command. I have triple checked that I'm looking at the right directory as well as have checked that there is no period at the start of the file.

any advice as to why ubuntu is not recognizes newly made documents?

thanks in advance !

Comment: What is the file name? What is the current working directory of yours?